# Most crucial elements in a light-weight C++ coding standard

Tags: c++, coding-style

I've been involved in developing coding standards which were quite elaborate. My own experience is that it was hard to enforce if you don't have proper processes to maintain it and strategies to uphold it.

Now I'm working in, and leading, an environment even less probable to have processes and follow-up strategies in quite a while. Still I want to uphold some minimum level of respectable code. So I thought I would get good suggestions here, and we might together produce a reasonable light-weight subset of the most important coding standard practices for others to use as reference.

So, to emphasize the essence here:

### **What elements of a C++ coding standard are the most crucial to uphold?**

- ### Answering/voting rules

  - 1 candidate per answer, preferably with a **brief** motivation.
  - **Vote down** candidates which focuses on style and subjective formatting guidelines. This is not to indicate them as unimportant, only that they are less relevant in this context.
  - **Vote down** candidates focusing on how to comment/document code. This is a larger subject which might even deserve its own post.
  - **Vote up** candidates that clearly facilitates safer code, which minimizes the risk of enigmatic bugs, which increases maintainability, etc.
  - **Don't cast your vote** in any direction on candidates you are uncertain about. Even if they sound reasonable and smart, or on the contrary "something surely nobody would use", your vote should be based on clear understanding and experience.

Comment: It is likely that here you will create an incohesive collection of rules, most of which won't address problems resulting in undefined behaviour.

Comment: An alternative approach, is to take an existing coding standard (eg. AV JSF, MISRA C++, www.codingstandard.com) and then post the rules you feel are good candidates.

Comment: how can style be worth a down-vote. You ask for best practices in standards, then insist on ignoring the best. Code where everyone chooses their own naming convention (for example) is the worst readable possible. Vote how you like, brothers!

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Please try to understand the purpose here. Style is important, but if you were to pick the (let's say) 10 most important things to have in your light-weight easy-reviewable standard in absense of any process whatsovever, - then style should have pretty low priority.

Comment: I like the way that currently the top two options "keep functions under 25 lines", and "sprinkle asserts all over the place" are nigh-on mutually contradictory. If you want to do both, buy a taller monitor ;-)

Comment: @Robert, I do consider process to be part of style - its the 'soft' side of standards. Make sure the standard is about how to control it in a more accessible and structured way, not telling people to use asserts, or have 25 line functions. eg. directory structure used is my top priority.

Answer (score 68):

Prefer [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

STL's auto (and shared in boost & C++0x) pointers may help.

Comment: i would say "prefer RAII" - i certainly wouldn't require it in a standard.

Comment: Agreed. One place I worked people would argue symantics like "perfer". Eventually our standard was written like everything was an absolute requirement (dispite being able to deviate from it after a review).

Comment: Without RAII, it's quite difficult to write error-safe code that's easy to maintain.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the term "RAII" until recently. I always considered the concept as "common sense".

Comment: It amazes me how many C++ programmers don't know the RAII idiom.  I've had to enforce this with a rule saying "Never use 'new' without checking with the team lead."

Comment: @kris, i like that a lot

Answer (score 58):

Use `const` identifiers by default.  They provide guarantees for the reader/maintainer, and are way easier to build in than to insert afterwards.

Both member variables and methods would be declared `const`, as well as function arguments.  `const` member variables enforce proper use of the initializer list.

A side-effect of this rule: avoid methods with side-effects.

------ EDIT

`const` member *variables* seemed like a good idea; this is not always the case: they effectively make *any* object immutable.  This becomes problematic for e.g. sorting a vector.

```
struct A {
    const int i;
};

bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {
    return lhs.i < rhs.i;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<A> as;
    as.emplace_back(A{1});
    std::sort(begin(as), end(as));
}
```

error message:

```
... note: copy assignment operator of 'A' is implicitly deleted because
field 'i' is of const-qualified type 'const int'
...
in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::sort<...>'
requested here

    std::sort(begin(as), end(as));
```

Comment: So easy to use, and so much more safety in the code. +1. In fact, this is more important than the amusing "use if(0 == p) instead of if(p == 0)"...

Comment: Indeed, have p const, and you won't have to worry about `if (p=0)`.

Comment: Voted up, but I'd suggest making it clearer that you are talking about *methods* as well as just data items.

Comment: Good point about inserting const later - that's painful... +1

Answer (score 48):

### Use C++ casts instead of C casts

use:

- `static_cast`
- `const_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `dynamic_cast`

but never C-style casts.

**How it clearly facilitates safer code, which minimizes the risk of enigmatic bugs, which increases maintainability, etc.**

Each cast has limited powers. E.g., if you want to remove a const (for whatever reason), `const_cast` won't change the type at the same time (which could be a bug difficult to find).

Also, this enables a reviewer to search for them and then, the coder to justify them if needed.

Comment: Moreover a C cast is always handled as a reinterpret_cast<> when dealing with forward declarations. And C casts is unable to correctly downcast or crosscast.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but I don't know that I would recommend reinterpret\_cast either...

Comment: This conflicts with the "use weakest possible cast" rule, as reinterpret_cast is stronger than C-style cast and sometimes you have nothing between it and static_cast other than c-style cast. For instance, converting a pointer to a byte buffer to a struct{} (regular binary parsing pattern). Would you recommend a reinterpret_cast? I think not.

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky, this is exactly one of the cases for `reinterpret_cast<>`.  `reinterpret_cast<>` is designed for converting between `Foo*` and `Bar*`, where `Foo` and `Bar` are completely different types (in your example, `std::uint8*` and `struct foo`.

`reinterpret_cast<>` is also weaker than a C-style cast, because it cannot cast away `const` or `volatile`

Answer (score 39):

Use references instead of pointers where possible. This prevents constant defensive NULL checks.

Comment: But if you dereference a pointer to initialize the reference, make sure the pointer isn't NULL first!

Comment: Yes - but if you always used references you wouldn't have that pointer to begin with! I'm kidding... I've been bitten by the very issue you bring up many times.

Comment: +1 to the effect, not to the reasoning.  i sometimes return null iterator, e.g. find(). is that bad?  higher level languages that use reference types typically have a `None` object.

Comment: @Dustin Getz - so what reasoning would you like to see? I'll edit.

Comment: @Dustin, @Aardvark: The problem is that if you return a reference then you're kind of forced to use exceptions to indicate failure rather than testing a returned pointer for NULL. However, if you don't need the error checking, use a reference because it prevents a lot of stupid mistakes. It also makes code a little easier to read. I'd also advocate using references to simulate Pascal's `with`, e.g. `SubClassType &sub = SomePtr->SomeLowerLevel[index]->member;` and then you use `sub`.

Answer (score 36):

Make sure that your compiler's warning level is set high enough (/Wall preferably) so that it will catch silly mistakes like:

```
if (p = 0)
```

when you really meant

```
if (p == 0)
```

so that you don't need to resort to even sillier tricks like:

```
if (0 == p)
```

which degrade the readability of your code.

Comment: ... and compile with WISE (Warning is Error)

Comment: Another way: If p is const, then if(p = 0) won't compile anyway, but this is another post...

Comment: For moderation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237719/
I am surprised myself and not happy about how much of a nerve it hit. Nonetheless, I think it is a valuabe rule!

Comment: Unfortunately, MSVC's C++ libraries have many of errors with `/W4`, and hundreds at `/Wall`

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I've run into that problem. Fortunately, it's solvable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525677/is-there-a-way-to-disable-all-warnings-with-a-pragma

Answer (score 34):

### Use vector and string instead of C-style arrays and char *

Use **std::vector** whenever you need to create a buffer of data, even if the size is fixed.

Use **std::string** whenever you need to have a string.

**How it clearly facilitates safer code, which minimizes the risk of enigmatic bugs, which increases maintainability, etc.?**

**std::vector:** The user of a vector can always find its size, and the vector can be resized if needed. It can even be given (through the (&(myVector[0])) notation) to a C API. Of course, the vector will clean after itself.

**std::string:** Almost the same reasons above.And the fact it will always be correctly initialized, that it can't be overrun, that it will handle modifications gracefully, like concatenations, assignation, etc, and in a natural way (using operators instead of functions)

Comment: The problem with this is that I write a lot of OS-interface code, which makes heavy use of char arrays. Having some kind of standard that required me to use std::string for objects that are never accessed as anything but char arrays would lead to a lot of dumb code.

Comment: The solution, then, would be to interface the OS API with C++ friendly methods. I worked on such thing to interface my C++ code with raw Win32 API, and usually, it is Ok. And my C++ interface checked for "GetLastError" and logged the info, which no developer did on its own!

Comment: for domain specific solutions (drivers and such), of course you can prefer native APIs, so long as you can justify it.

Comment: @Dustin Getz: Of course, you're right. Drivers are low level APIs themselves, the constraints are very specifics, so the solution usually are, too

Comment: What is `std::string`? Maybe you meant `std::wstring`? :)

Comment: @280Z28 : I assume you are joking, of course. For those not knowing the difference between std::string and std::wstring, the first is a std::basic_string templated to "char" and the second is the same std::basic_string, but this time templated to "wchar_t".

Comment: I know this is years later, but I think @280Z28 was joking that no one should be using anything but wide chars in new code so the code will support internationalization.

Answer (score 32):

Keep functions to a reasonable size. Personally, I like to keep functions under 25 lines. Readability is enhanced when you can take a function in as a unit rather than having to scan up and down trying to figure out how it works. If you have to scroll to read it, it makes matters even worse.

Comment: It's indeed important. And it is a consequence of : "a function must do only one thing, and do it well"

Comment: I've worked on jobs that had McCabe complexity limits for all functions. The cutoff was kind of arbitrary some times, but the overall effect forced smaller routines, which was great.

Answer (score 31):

[assert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert#Usage) all assumptions, including temporary assumptions, like unimplemented behavior.  assert function entry and exit conditions if nontrivial.  assert all nontrivial intermediate states.  your program should never crash without an assert failing first.  you can customize your assert mechanism to ignore future occurances.

> Use error-handling code for conditions you expect to occur; use assertions for conditions that should never occur. Error handling typically checks for bad input data; assertions check for bugs in the code.
>
> If error-handling code is used to address an anomalous condition, the error handling will enable the program to respond to the error gracefully. If an assertion is fired for an anomalous condition, the corrective action is not merely to handle an error gracefully—the corrective action is to change the program's source code, recompile, and release a new version of the software. A good way to think of assertions is as executable documentation—you can't rely on them to make the code work, but they can document assumptions more actively than program-language comments can [1].

1. McConnell, Steve. Code Complete, Second Edition. Microsoft Press © 2004. Chapter 8 - Defensive Programming

Comment: I would even add: compiletime assert where possible.

Comment: Regarding Programming by Contract, see also B.Meyer book, and M.Wilson's Imperfect C++.

Comment: I would even add: release-time check at nearly all places where you have debug-time assert(). The only reason to have one without the other is performance, which is seldom a resonable subject for optimization.

Answer (score 29):

### Know who is owner of *that* memory.

- create objects on stack as much as possible (no useless new)
- Avoid transfer of ownership unless really needed
- Use RAII and smart pointers
- If transfer of ownership is mandated (without smart pointers), then, document clearly the code (the functions should have a non-ambiguous name, always using the same name pattern, like "char * allocateMyString()" and "void deallocateMyString(char * p)".

**How it clearly facilitates safer code, which minimizes the risk of enigmatic bugs, which increases maintainability, etc.?**

Not having a clear memory ownership philosophy leads to interesting bugs or memory leaks, and time lost wondering if the char * returned by this function should be deallocated by the user, or not, or given back to a special deallocation function, etc..

As much as possible, the function/object allocating the memory must be the function/object deallocating it.

Comment: I'd add that the "owner" policy should also include a "transfer of ownership" policy.

Answer (score 27):

Side note: Do not impose SESE (*Single Entry Single Exit*) (i.e. do not forbid more than one `return`, the use of `break`/`continue`/...)

In C++, this is an utopia as `throw` is another return point. 
SESE had two advantages in C and exception-less languages:

- the deterministic release of resources that is now neatly handled by the RAII idiom in C++,
- making functions easier to maintain, that should not be a concern as the functions **must** be kept short (as specified by the rule of "one function, one responsibility")

Comment: I disagree that single point of return ever made functions easier to maintain. It usually just complicates the function body unnecessarily.

Comment: Greg, I totally agree with you. I don't think a SESE function is easier to read. Some think so, but it is not my case either.

Comment: Modding up, but I generally don't mind such requirements, because there is almost *never* more than one exit point from a routine or loop. There might be more than one place the exit *came from*, but never more than one point it goes to. Without goto's *all* routines are single exit point.

Comment: ..another way to look at this is that if you have exceptions, *all* your routines and loops are multiple exit anyway. :-)

Answer (score 26):

### Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Write safe and correct code first.

Then, if you have performance problems, and if your profiler told you the code is slow, you can try to optimize it.

Never believe you will optimize snippets of code better than the compiler.

When looking for optimizations, study the algorithms used, and potentially better alternatives.

**How it clearly facilitates safer code, which minimizes the risk of enigmatic bugs, which increases maintainability, etc.?**

Usually, "optimized" (or supposedly optimized) code is a lot less clearer, and tend to express itself through raw, near-the-machine way, instead of a more business-oriented way. Some optimizations rely of switchs, if, etc., and then will be more difficult to test because of multiple code paths.

And of course, optimization before profiling often lead to zero performance gain.

Answer (score 24):

Curly braces for any control statement.  (Thanks to own experience and reinforced by reading Code Complete v2):

```
// bad example - what the writer wrote
if( i < 0 ) 
    printf( "%d\n", i );
    ++i; // this error is _very_ easy to overlook!  

// good example - what the writer meant
if( i < 0 ) {
    printf( "%d\n", i );
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: if (i<0) printf; \n    ++i; //easy to spot

Comment: That's right.  But not generally applicable for longer conditions and statements.

Comment: shrug, i think its subjective.  for early bailout type checks the braces just get in the way.  i'd be annoyed if this was in a coding standard.

Comment: the indentation is more important than the braces - that's what shows you where something should be, the "++i;" will always stand out in well-indented code.

Comment: I agree.  I see no advantage in leaving out the braces, only potential problems.

Comment: -1 shortening code is important. Proper indentation seems to solve these problems, and misindentation problems are easy to spot during CR.

Comment: this is subjective, but in my book avoiding potential mistakes is more important than having less curly braces to look at

Answer (score 15):

Prefer standard-compliant code.  Prefer to use the standard libraries.

Comment: Too bad this item is justified. Too many out there that justify their code by the only mean of "works for me" ...

Answer (score 12):

Only trivial use of the ? : operator, i.e.

```
float x = (y > 3) ? 1.0f : -1.0f;
```

is ok, but this is not:

```
float x = foo(2 * ((y > 3) ? a : b) - 1);
```

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this rule, but I think the non-trivial example you give is perfectly fine. I would disallow nested ternary operators.

Comment: The ternary operator should be reserved to the cases where the result is more important than the test. BTW, it quite useful to use const pro-activelly.

Comment: Really, the second example violates my rule of only one thing per line. An assignment with the operator? would make this code readable. In shorter terms, this is'nt an example of bad operator? use.

Comment: This shouldn't be in a coding standard because there's no objective definition of good/bad. It'd be covered in an introductory statement "Write clear, maintainable code."

Comment: I agree with Ferruccio.  That example is ok, it is the nested form that gives me headaches.

Comment: +0: I disagree. Arithmetic should nearly always be preferred to conditionals, even inlined. Reduces **cyclomatic complexity**

Comment: @Ferrucio: you can even make the nested one readable, though I'd consider replacing them with named functions. Readability example (open up your favoured editor and replace \n with \n (D'oh): `const Foo x = frob ? bar  : \n              frob ? bar  : \n              frob ? bar  : \n              damn;`  (edit: and align them properly; SO-comments are not good for code ...)

Answer (score 9):

Use a lint tool - i.e. PC-Lint. This will catch many of the 'structural' coding guideline issues. Meaning things that read to actual bugs rather than style/readability issues. (Not that readability is not important, but it is less so than actual errors).

Example, rather than requiring this style:

```
if (5 == variable)
```

As a way of preventing the 'unintended assignment' bug, let lint find it.

Comment: I advocate exactly this in my company.  Lint should always be used, and will catch this problem.  Plus, any experienced dev won't make this mistake anymore (not even a typo).  Lastly, visually, the style with the constant first is hard on my eyes... so kudos, I agree.

Comment: Placing the constant first harms readability by diffusing the flow of information. I absolutely agree with letting the tools do their job here.

Answer (score 9):

### Never use structs without proper constructors

structs are legal C++ constructs, used to aggregate data together. Still, the data should be always properly initialized.

All C++ structs should have at least a default constructor, which will set its aggregated data to default values.

```
struct MyStruct // BAD
{
   int i ; bool j ; char * k ;
}

struct MyStruct // GOOD
{
   MyStruct() : i(0), j(true), k(NULL) : {}

   int i ; bool j ; char * k ;
}
```

And if they are usually initialized in some way, provide a constructor to enable the user to avoid a C-style struct initialization:

```
MyStruct oMyStruct = { 25, true, "Hello" } ; // BAD
MyStruct oMyStruct(25, true, "Hello") ;      // GOOD
```

**How it clearly facilitates safer code, which minimizes the risk of enigmatic bugs, which increases maintainability, etc.?**

Having struct without a proper constructor leaves the user of this struct the task of initializing it. So, the following code will be copy pasted from function to function:

```
void doSomething()
{
   MyStruct s = { 25, true, "Hello" } ;
  // Etc.
}

void doSomethingElse()
{
   MyStruct s = { 25, true, "Hello" } ;
  // Etc.
}

// Etc.
```

Which means that, in C++, if you need to add a field in the struct, or change the order of the internal data, you have to go through all these initializations to verify each is still correct. With a proper constructor, modifying the internals of the structs is decoupled from its use.

Comment: The interesting part about this answer is that I disagree with the title, but very strongly agree with the text.

Comment: You're right: I'll change the title...

Comment: A constructor makes the type a non-POD. How do you create a POD struct?

Comment: @MSalters: Good question, the answer being already given above, but not clearly, it's true: In C++, avoid POD structs as much as possible...

Comment: Note that "PODs" structures/classes in C++ have little to none advantage over non-PODs ones. The only moment you'll consider using a POD (or a POD-like) is when interfacing with a C API.

Comment: If you really need a POD, you can use inheritance to create the version with a constructor. Useful also if the struct is part of a library or API you can't modify.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Yes, this solution was explored for a Win32 API struct in the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112085/is-this-c-structure-initialization-trick-safe#112100

Comment: If you are simply initializing the values of `i` and `k` to defaults for the type, you should use `i(), k()` instead. That way the items in the initializer list that have particular meaning to that constructor are the only ones with specific values in parentheses.

Comment: @280Z28 : Remember the types of i and k are C/C++ built-in types, which means that they ARE NOT initialized by default. So, using the "i()" notation on C/C++ built-in types means you'll probably have problems (i.e. bugs) later because of semi-random values poping out... ^_^ ...

Comment: In C++03, PODs are the only way to portably create `static` `const` data structures (and arrays thereof) that don't require runtime initialisation. Ignore at your own peril (or use C++0x `constexpr`).

Comment: @parcebal: Check the different between *default initialization* and *value initialization*.  @280Z28 may be a little loose in his terminology, but the code he recommends is correct and not random or uninitialized.

Comment: A better version of this rule might be:  Use Aggregate/POD structs only where required.  Then, if there isn't already (I am only half way through this list) there can be a rule that says all user defined non-POD/Aggregate types shall have a constructor.  As written, I don't think much of this.

Answer (score 8):

Don't add types or functions to the global namespace.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but the rationale is missing:  you pollute the global namespace by doing it and thereby potentially causing a whole lot problems if the name exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 8):

**[Principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)**.

Maybe it's not the "flavor" of rules you are looking for, but I'd definitely put it first.

It is not only the root, reason and sanity check for all the boring stuff like formatting and commenting guidelines, but - to me more importantly - puts the emphasis on the code being read and understood, rather than just compiled.

It also covers the only reasonable code quality measure I have ever encountered - [WTF's per minute](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m).

I'd use that first point to stress the importance and value of clear, consistent code, and to motivate the following items in the coding standard.

Answer (score 6):

Forbid `t[i]=i++;` `f(i++,i);`, and so on as there is no (portable) guarantees regarding what is executed first.

Comment: I would have to look it up, but I can hardly believe the Standard leaves this construct undetermined.

Comment: "Undefined" is the word.
What specifiy how the instructions are sequenced are the Sequence points, and there is no sequence point between the two evaluations of i and i++ in both examples.
This is actually a quite well known issue in C&C++. See the FAQ C++ lite §39.15 and §39.16

Comment: Again, this shouldn't be in a written coding standard because it just clutters up the document with obvious information.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not that obvious for everybody. Still your comment is interresting. It raises a new question: where does the obvious starts and where does it ends? Because in the end, a standard is about safety rules that are well known and understood by a few people.

Comment: What? you might as well forbid my favorite: 
   `const double PI = 3.141592653658979;`
   `*(double*)&PI = 4;`

Seriously, if you're going to talk about actual errors being disallowed in a style document, the document would be infinitely long!

Answer (score 5):

Always, always, always do proper data member initialization on object construction.

I ran into a problem where an object constructor was relying on some "default" initialization for its data members.  Building the code under two platforms (Windows/Linux) gave different results and a hard-to-find memory bug.  The result was that a data member was not initialized in the constructor, and used before it was initialized.  On one platform (Linux), the compiler initialized it to what the code writer thought appropriate default.  On Windows, the value was initialized to something - but garbage.  On use of the data member, everything went haywire.  Once the initialization was fixed - no more problem.

Answer (score 4):

If the toolchain in use (or projected use) has an inefficient implementation of *exceptions*, it might be wise to avoid their use. I've worked under such conditions.

Update: [here](http://www.caravan.net/ec2plus/rationale.html) is someone else's rationale for "Embedded C++", which seems to exclude exceptions. It makes the following points:

- It is difficult to estimate the time between when an exception has occurred and control has passed to a corresponding exception handler.
- It is difficult to estimate memory consumption for exception handling.

There is more elaborate text on that page, I didn't want to copy it all. Plus, it's 10  years old so it might be of no use any longer, which is why I included the part about the toolchain. Perhaps that should also read "if memory is not considered a major problem", and/or "if predictable real-time response is not required", and so on.

Comment: Very interesting. Please edit and elaborate a bit more on why this is so.

Comment: domain specific argument. if you're not using exceptions, you need to understand why they are awesome, have metrics documenting why they aren't 'whatever' enough and how much more 'whatever' they need to be, and be really upset that you can't use them. Only then should you stop using them.

Comment: There are very specific reasons for not using exceptions, however, EC++ is not the definitive source I would use.  EC++ bans lots of features from C++ and actually caused the ISO C++ Committee to respond to the claims that were made by the standard.

Comment: The only valid reason I've read to not use exceptions is when we are dealing with a legacy code that does nothing about exceptions -- see google C++ Coding Standard.

Comment: Richar Corden is right. Just reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C%2B%2B , and that they removed namespaces, templates and C++ casts show AC++ was a joke more than anything else

Comment: good point about different standards required for different environments. Aircraft avionics will require different ones to a website, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Method and variable names in a common naming scheme for consistency; I don't tend to be bother much by anything else while reading source.

Answer (score 4):

Public inheritance must model The Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP).

Code reuse/import without substituability must be implemented with private inheritance when a very strong coupling makes sense, or with aggregation otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

### Beware of C API

The C API can be very efficient, but will need exposed raw data (i.e. pointers, etc.), which won't help the safety of the code. Use existing C++ API instead, or encapsulate the C API with C++ code.

e.g.:

```
// char * d, * s ;
strcpy(d, s) ; // BAD

// std::string d, s ;
d = s ;        // GOOD
```

### Never use strtok

strtok is not reentrant. Which means that if one strtok is started while another is not ended, one will corrupt the "internal data" of the other.

**How it clearly facilitates safer code, which minimizes the risk of enigmatic bugs, which increases maintainability, etc.?**

Using C API means using raw types, which can lead to interesting bugs like buffer overflow (and potential stack corruption) when a sprintf goes too far (or string cropping when using snprintf, which is a kind of data corruption). Even when working on raw data, malloc can be easily abused, as shown by the following code:

```
int * i = (int *) malloc(25) ; // Now, I BELIEVE I have an array of 25 ints!
int * j = new int[25] ;        // Now, I KNOW I have an array of 25 ints!
```

Etc. etc..

As for strtok: C and C++ are stack-enabled languages, that enable to user to not care about what functions are above his own on the stack, and what functions will be called below his own on the stack. strtok removes this freedom of "not caring"

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using generated copy constructor and operator= by default.

- If you want your object to be copiable.

  - If every attribute can be trivially copied, comment clearly you are using implicit copy constructor and operator= deliberately.
  - Otherwise, write your own constructors, using the initialization field to initialize attributes and following the header order (which is the real construction order).
- If still don't know (*default option*) or you think you dont want to copy the objects of a certain class, declare its copy constructor and operator= as private. This way the compiler will let you know when you are doing something you don't want to do.

```
    class foo
    {
       //...
    private:
       foo( const foo& );
       const foo& operator=( const foo& );
    };
```

Or in a [cleaner way](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) if you are using boost:

```
    class foo : private boost::noncopyable
    {
      ...
    };
```

Comment: This rule is two simplistic. When all the attributes are copyable and assignable, AND when we want the new class to be copyable and assignalble, we must prefer the default generated copy-constructor and assignement operator. In those cases, we should consider leaving a comment stating that this is a deliberate choice as all the members are copyable and assignable.
We are back to my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242728/most-crucial-elements-in-a-light-weight-c-coding-standard/243256#243256

Comment: Yes, if the commentary is clear enough to prevent anybody to add a new non trivial-copy attribute to the class, breaking the initial assumptions.

Comment: Edited to clarify this rule is tells you that you should avoid using them by default, and make the non-copyable behavior the default option.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever guidelines, make it very **easy** to recognize applicability: the less choice you have, the less time you loose choosing.  And the easier it becomes to brainparse the code.

Examples of 'hard to recognize':

- No braces if only one line in the conditional body
- Use K&R brace placement for namespaces, but put brace underneath conditions in function definition code
- ...

Answer (score 2):

A point should be dedicated to explain the difference between value semantics and entity semantics. It could provide the typical code snippets about how copy is handled is the various cases.

See also [Checklist for writing copy constuctor and assignment operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214891/checklist-for-writing-copy-constuctor-and-assignment-operator-in-c#214966)

Answer (score 2):

Probably a no-brainer, but nevertheless an important rule:

Avoid undefined behavior.

There's an awful lot of it in C++, and it's probably impossible to write a nontrivial application that doesn't depend on it somehow, but the general rule should still be "undefined behavior is bad". (Because sadly there are C++ programmers out there who feels that "it works on my machine/compiler" is good enough).

If you have to rely on it, make it clear to everyone what, why, where and how.

Comment: I think I have developed many non-trivial C++ applications that don't depend on undefined behaviour

Comment: I think you just don't realize that they depend on undefined behavior. ;)

Comment: I think I have developed many non-trivial C++ applications that don't depend on undefined behaviour, and I am pretty certain of it. If you know C++ very well, it's a very, very tangible task ;)

Comment: @phresnel: were all your apps singlethreaded? Multithreading is undefined behavior in C++03. Just an example ;)

Comment: ?? Whether multithreading is undefined behaviour or not solely depends on how the multithreading library is implemented. "Multithreading is not defined in C++2003" is completely different from "Multithreading is undefined behaviour". The set phrase and meaning of "undefined behaviour" is well defined in the C++ standard, it is **not** some colloquial term.

Comment: @phresnel: C++03 doesn't have a memory model. No library can make up for that fundamental deficiency. The whole concept of having multiple executions of the same program running concurrently and sharing data is undefined. There is *nothing* in the language that says when, how or if data written by one thread should ever become visible to another. Anything that relies on such data sharing relies on undefined behavior.

Comment: How about the union trick for converting (specifically reinterpreting the underlying bits) between types (say, `int` and `float`? Ever used that? That's undefined behavior. When you get down to it, C++ contains a lot of iffy bits and pieces that *ought* to be well specified, but are left undefined.

Comment: @jalf: So if I interface with a synchronous, task based multithreading library written in haskell, through a handful of `extern "C"` functions whom I pass some write only data, then waiting for the return value synchronously, this is undefined behaviour in any case? You are right if you attribute your phrase with a "probably", but it is definitely not a necessity. C is not the only way to write C-callable functions. (...)

Comment: (...) Apart, non-triviality does not imply multi-threading. And no, I am not using the union trick in portable variants of my code, at maximum I use it in #ifdef-imprisoned optional code. I prolly expressed myself poorly, but I don't never use compiler specific code, but I usually do not *rely* on it. You are surely not entirely wrong with your multi-threading example, but I am also right in that it is *possible*  to invoke multithreading without entering the Dark Realm, and in that I've written many non-trivial portable applications.

Comment: @jalf: Btw, C++03 **does** have a memory model, even if a "bit" simplicistic. C++0x will "just" reconstruct it.

Comment: @phresnel: then show me where in the standard it is specified. (hint: it isn't)

Comment: re. multithreading, your haskell example may get away with it because the C++ code is singlethreaded, and merely calls out to another library, written in another language, which has well-defined threading semantics. I'm sure you've written many portable apps, but that doesn't mean there's no undefined behavior in them. How about signed integer overflow? Using `operator <` to compare pointers which point to different arrays? `a[i] == ++i`?

Comment: @jalf: ANSI ISO IEC 14882 2003, **1.7 "Memory Model" [intro.memory]**, as mentioned, it's simplicistic: `The fundamental storage unit in the C + + memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the
number of which is implementation-defined. The least significant bit is called the low-order bit; the most significant bit is called the high-order bit. The memory available to a C + + program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every byte has a unique address.`

Comment: @jalf: I neither compare pointers (mainly because I don't use them generally), nor do I rely on overflow. If I really need signed types that do not obey the law of arithmetic modulo (as per section [basic.fundamental]), I'll write a class that implements this behaviour. Next comes overlapping arrays, mutating a const_casted value that was declared const, infinite template recursion, throwing from destructors, accessing non-static data members in function-try-blocks, specifying a number<=0 or >32767 in #line. I know, I know. It is becoming slightly ridicoulus.

Comment: @phresnel: fair enough. I obviously can't know if there's any undefined behavior in code I haven't read. I think my point is clear though, that there are a lot of subtle pitfalls that nearly everyone accidentally rely on, but which are undefined behavior. But you might be the 1-in-a-million exception. ;)

Comment: By "memory model", we usually mean the semantics of what it means to read from, and write to memory: particularly, when does a write become visible to other threads. C++03 does not have *any* memory model of this kind. And without this, any attempt at making a write from one thread visible to another is fundamentally undefined.

Comment: ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_%28computing%29) describes "memory model as follows: "In computing, a Memory model describes: how threads interact through memory, or more generally: specify what assumptions the compiler is allowed to make when generating code for segmented memory or paged memory platforms." C++03 describes none of that. it merely says what a bit and a byte is. That would usually not be considered a memory model, regardless of the section title. ;)

Comment: Fair enough, C++ parlance is sometimes different from common IT parlance. I think that I am not an exception, though, but we lack the statistics for this discussion ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pass input arguments by const reference, and output or input-output arguments by pointer. This is a rule borrwed from the Google style guide.

I used to have an absolute aversion to pointers and preferred to use references whenever possible (as suggested by one of the posters in this thread). However, adopting this output-arg-as-pointer convention has made my functions much more readable. For example,

```
SolveLinearSystem(left_hand_side, right_hand_side, &params);
```

makes it clear that "params" is being written to.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces required if you have more than one step of indentation:

```
if (bla) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    foo();
}
```

This helps to keep indentation in line with how the compiler sees the code.

Comment: I like this better than "always use curly braces."

Comment: 'not always' is one of the choices that burdens the brain understanding the code.  'always' leads to 1. less choice=>less time spent choosing and 2. less occasion to write bugs overlooked by indentation (especially for people who also write python...)

Comment: format for readability with braces or whitespace, but i certainly think requiring them is arbitrary.

Comment: @xtofl: even if you're supposed to always do it one way, the compiler takes more than that, so ignorant cases are inevitable.  i'd argue brainparsing braces doesn't burden the brain - it becomes rote.

Answer (score 1):

I think a coding standard document isn't the solution to this problem.  The solution is to motivate your labor to learn/care about the human side of coding - "code for people first and computers last".

Obviously it is not possible to just fire the ones that don't care - but a standard document isn't going to help them much, either.

Comment: I partially agree. Motivating coders to proper coding is good to limit the fix-this-and-that list created in code reviews. However I believe some parts of a standard are not automatically achieved by relying on common sense, for example const correctness.

Comment: sure, but if they are motivated and care, teach them const once and they use it forever out of pride.  if they don't care, it will be half assed to meet the min spec.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest just requiring developers to read a bunch of guidelines, and the effective C++ and more effective C++ books by Meyers.

If you want lightweight, you are going to have to rely on common sense and a common ideal.

Code reviews help enforce this as well.

To keep it lightweight I would avoid a document and code police.  Praise good code publicly.

EDIT - I started with a comment here, but will put it in the response for ease of viewing:

reviews done correctly will do wonders - but you can't allow reporting hierarchies into the review and no statistics with people's names can be on the review results.

Make sure to keep the document small and be sure to give REASONS for the "rule"/guideline.  Without that then you ae just demanding blind obedience.  With rationale and reasons you educate so that actually posting/writing the "rule" becomes unneeded.  (as the concept will be internalized)

Comment: Light-weight indeed relies heavily on common sense. In my opinion a document should exist so anyone can read and everyone knows the shots (especially juniors). Policework and court-style reviews are shadows from failing leadership and communication.

Answer (score 1):

The Art of Computer Programming Tome{1,2,3}

Answer (score 1):

Base your coding style off of "C++ Coding Standard" (Sutter/Alexandrescu), and only document where you deviate from it. I cannot take any "C++ Coding Standard" serious that doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

**Rule 0 should always be:**

### **Document any deviations from this standard**

Some problems may necessitate non-adherence to a particular standard.

These cases **must** be documented and justified because they indicate a deviation from the expected idioms in the codebase.

Not documenting them can cause bugs because:

1. A future maintainer may bring the code to compliance without
   understanding why it was non-compliant in the first place.
2. A future developer may expect the code to conform and so make
   incorrect assumptions about its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The best standards are those that are small and tightly focussed on what really matters to making quality code. They do not try to teach coding, they do not try to force a particular way of coding. They generally stick to consistency features and subjective reviews (eg, if the rest of your team think a piece of code is readable, fits with the consistency rules, and is commented, then its always going to be good code)

So to re-emphasise: consistency - naming convention, whitespace management, commenting blocks, directory structure. Nothing else *really* matters

Edit for Dustin:
the big problem with standards comes with the exceptions. If you have a standard that says "1 statement per line", you cannot write the following made-up example:

```
SetColText(1,"col1"); SetColWidth(1, 10);
SetColText(2,"col1"); SetColWidth(2, 10);
...
SetColText(9,"col1"); SetColWidth(9, 10);
```

But I'd say that was more readable, and therefore less error-prone that splitting them up. (I'm sure you can come up with better examples).

This is my point - telling people how to write code, and how to format it to strict rules is always going to fall over in ways and places you didn't anticipate. So its far better to trust your coders to do it right after enforcing a few rules. If they have a few rules to follow, they will write good, disciplined code so you won't need the rest of the crappy rules.

You see some standards that go on for pages and pages. (The Philips C# one is 48 fecking pages long!)

So, given that you have a team of quality coders, what do you need to do to make it easier to work with their code? the answer is always consistency of 'where' they put the code, not how they write it. eg. you always have a bin, and obj directory in your project is a good standard. You can pick up any project and know where things are .. unlike someone building all his binaries in his c:/mybin directory because its easier for him.

Comment: i dunno, man.  one you can brainparse c++ you can brainparse ANY c++.  i think the important values relate to managing complexity.  i guess i agree with the subjective review part, but i sure don't agree with the latter part

Answer (score 0):

### Limit the types you use

If you need to use an integer type, choose one and keep it. This will avoid the problems associated with mixing of short, int, long, etc.. types.

```
// BAD
int i ;
long j ;
short k ;

// GOOD (if you choose the "int" as integer)
int i ;
int j ;
int k ;
```

The same goes for real types: Choose one (e.g. double), and do not use another.

Etc.

Note: There is still the issue of signed/unsigned, which can't always be avoided, and the fact STL use its own integer types (i.e. std::vector::size_type), but all the remaining code should not mixing.

Note 2: You could use typedef to "choose" your prefered type for signed integer and real numbers. This would enable a low-cost change if needed.

**How it clearly facilitates safer code, which minimizes the risk of enigmatic bugs, which increases maintainability, etc.?**

Some bugs are created by comparing unsigned type to signed types, mysterious loss of precision, or integer under/overflow.

Compilers usually send warnings at compile time, but then, the usually answer is to "cast" the warning away, which can help hide the error.

#### Edit

plinth made an useful comment I'll copy paste here:

> Having written a lot of code that has to interact with things at the hardware level, I can't say much for this guideline. For this level of work, I prefer the integral types to be abstracted to names that include the precision (ie, int16, uint16, int32, uint32, etc.) – plinth Aug 18 at 20:50

plinth is right, of course. Sometimes you have to deal with int16, uint8 and other "precisely defined" types.

This does not invalidate the post above, only complete it.

The source of the bug is mixing different types (converting unsigned char into int, for example), thus, this kind of mixing must be avoided. The following rules thus apply:

- Choose one generic integral type (e.g. int), and stick to it when dealing with generic integers (the same can be said about reals)
- If (and only if) you need exact types (like uint8 or int16), use them
- Never mix different types.
- If you **really** must mix different types, then be very very cautious.

Below is an example of code that would break:

```
void * doAllocate(uint32 i)
{
   // try to allocate an array of "i" integers and returns it
}

void doSomething()
{
   uint32 i0 = 225 ;
   int8   i1 = 225 ;  // Oops...

   doAllocate(i0) ;   // This will try to allocate 255 integers
   doAllocate(i1) ;   // This will TRY TO allocate 4294967265
                      // integers, NOT 225
}
```

Comment: Having written a lot of code that has to interact with things at the hardware level, I can't say much for this guideline.  For this level of work, I prefer the integral types to be abstracted to names that include the precision (ie, int16, uint16, int32, uint32, etc.)

Comment: @plinth : This is a different problem. In the common cases, the coder wants to put an integer into a variable. Mixing types, both in size and in sign is a recipe to disaster. Usually, the coder needs a simple type able to hold all possible values. Choosing one and ONLY one is a good thing to do. <to be continued> ...

Comment: @plinth : <continuing> ... In your case, because you are working near the hardware, you NEED to use the exact type needed, thus, "int" or "short", which potentially varies with each compiler, is the wrong thing to do, thus, the need to use the exact type, like int32 or uint8. <to be continued> ...

Comment: @plinth : <continuing> ... But note that even near the hardware, converting a int8 into a uint32 will break unless you're very very careful. This means that in your case, instead of relying on ONE and ONLY ONE integer type like I advised, you must be either be careful to not mix them, or be very very careful when you DO mix them. Conclusion: Even if the solution I gave on my post (using one integer type only) can't be applied on your particular case, the reason (i.e. source of bugs when mixing) is still valid in your particular case, and thus, needs extra work/caution.

Comment: @plinth : <continuing> ... But note that even near the hardware, converting a int8 into a uint32 will break unless you're very very careful. This means that in your case, instead of relying on ONE and ONLY ONE integer type like I advised, you must be either be careful to not mix them, or be very very careful when you DO mix them. <to be continued> ...

Comment: @plinth : <continuing> ... Conclusion: Even if the solution I gave on my post (using one integer type only) can't be applied on your particular case, the reason described in my post (i.e. source of bugs when mixing) is still valid in your particular case, and thus, needs extra work/caution. This post is mostly aimed at coders who will think they are smarter just because they used an unsigned short instead of an int for "memory optimizations purposes". I met them, and I met their bugs, and it was not pleasant... ^_^ ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure destructors are defined as ***virtual***:

```
 class GoodClass {
 public:
   GoodClass();
   virtual ~GoodClass()
 };

 class BadClass {
 public:
   BadClass();
   ~BadClass()
 };
```

Comment: No. It makes no sense to have the destructors from value classes virtual. Moreover, in /C++ Coding Standards/ H.Sutter and A.Alexandrecu recommend to make the destructor from a *base class* either public and virtual, or protected and non virtual.

Comment: I agree with Sutter/Alexandrecu except I would go further and say it be a blanked rule for all destructors. 

My argument is a class may not be a base class today, but there is nothing to say it won't be a base class tommorrow. In this scenario the missing virtual is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: When the class is known to be a value class, inheriting it later will introduce many other problems. By saying clearly: "no this class is NOT meant to be (publicly) inherited" (thanks to the non-virtual destructor, and to a comment), we have a chance to avoid the problems.

Comment: If it is made a baseclass later, it will also get virtual methods. Then you can still make the dtor virtual. Otherwise at least gcc will geenerate a warning.

Answer (score -2):

No tabs (allows better use of external/other tools) and a fixed spaces inserted for tabs.

Comment: subjective style/formatting.  i prefer tabs.

Comment: I agree with this. Tabs change formatting in different editors, while spaces are consistent.

Comment: -1.  Tabs should always be used for indentation, everything else can be spaces, but tabs should always be used for indentation.

Comment: @owens, thats the point, my editor can show it to me the way I like it.

Comment: Tabs-vs.-spaces is a holy war.  No need to argue it here.

Comment: Tabs are a form of encapsulation and are preferable to spaces.  Anyone can change the 'size; of their tabs, but not so with spaces.

Comment: This is one area you do need to pick a rule (or _actually put in a tool_, not just handwave and say a tool _could_ do that). Code has to be either all-tabs or all-spaces, anything in between is broken.

Comment: @soru: there's also the code-block-indent-tabs + statement-indent-spaces, which gives you the flexibility of tabs, but doesn't break the look of multiline statements (e.g. `<tab><tab>const float f = ..., <tab><tab><12spaces>x = ...\n` (try it out in your editor); unfortunately, the lack of enforcing this in editors (and the lack of making fellows understand what this is about) made me "fall back" to all spaces, but I am not religious on this topic

Answer (score -7):

Sort functions in class declarations and definitions by name. This makes it easier to locate them in the .cpp file. Also, it frees your mind because you don't have to think about where to put your new function.

Comment: i group my methods by functionality - e.g. string::begin() would be adjacent to string::end()

Comment: Why not plop all your functions, class definitions, etc. into one file and alphabetize them?  Why not alphabetize #include lists?  Why not alphabetize instructions?

Comment: Yeah, this is silly.  I agree with Dustin.

Comment: Since the 70s (or even sooner?), locating can be done by your favourite editor's "find" facility, ans since the 90s, more and more IDEs have first class support for this.  The neat thing with "find" is that it works not only in your programming editor, but also in all web browsers, in your graphical OS of choice, in your text processor, and many more. By default, invoke "find" by pressing <ctrl>+<f>.

Comment: I think you guys should try it before dismissing this. Code Complete recommends it -- I tried it and never looked back.