# Is there a way to disable all warnings with a pragma?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pragma

I've started a new project and have decided to make sure it builds cleanly with the /Wall option enabled. The only problem is not all 3rd party libraries (like boost) compile without warnings, so I've resorted to doing this in a shared header:

```
#pragma warning(push)

#pragma warning(disable:4820)
#pragma warning(disable:4619)
#pragma warning(disable:4668)
#pragma warning(disable:4625)
#pragma warning(disable:4626)
#pragma warning(disable:4571)
#pragma warning(disable:4347)
#pragma warning(disable:4640)
#pragma warning(disable:4365)
#pragma warning(disable:4710)
#pragma warning(disable:4820)
#pragma warning(disable:4350)
#pragma warning(disable:4686)
#pragma warning(disable:4711)
#pragma warning(disable:4548)

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/integer.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#pragma warning(pop)
```

This works well enough, but every time I add new boost headers I have to add whatever warnings they generate to the list. Is there a way to say disable all warnings for this stretch of code?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can push/pop a low level of warning, like this:

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)        

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
// ...

#pragma warning(pop)
```

But know that it's not possible to disable *all* warnings. For example, some linker warnings are impossible to turn off.

Comment: I don't mean to condone necromancy but in your comment here I see a 1-to-1 relationship with the push/pop of warnings.  If I disable N warnings will I need to call pop N times?  Again, sorry to resurrect an old thread.

Comment: The number of warnings you disable is irrelevant. The number of 'pushes' has to match the number of 'pops' that's all.

Comment: Also, it is interesting to state that if `#pragma warning (pop)` is used, some warnings (4514 is an example) will still be issued, probably because these warning conditions are detected in some post-compilation context.

Answer (score 29):

```
#pragma warning(disable:4820)
#pragma warning(disable:4619)
#pragma warning(disable:4668)
```

for less lines....

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4820 4619 4668)
```

Answer (score 5):

What I've done before is set the "W3" option rather than "Wall" then in each of my own source .cpp files I put

```
#pragma warning(push, 4)
```

at the top AFTER all the "#include..." lines and then

```
#pragma warning(pop)
```

as the very last line of the file.

This way you get level 4 warnings in your code and level 3 in 3rd party code that you can't do anything about.

Comment: It seems to be more work to wrap every one of your own code files with a `#pragma warning` directive than to just wrap the offending 3rd party `#includes`. But if it works for you...

Answer (score 5):

Using the technique described in the [Assaf Lavie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/525712/7585517) it is possible to create helper macros:

```
#define DISABLE_ALL_WARNINGS_BEGIN \
    __pragma(warning(push, 0))

#define DISABLE_ALL_WARNINGS_END \
    __pragma(warning(pop))
```

They can be used in the following way ([online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XEcCMk)):

```
DISABLE_ALL_WARNINGS_BEGIN
void foo(int a)
{
    // this function should generate the following warning
    // "warning C4100: 'a': unreferenced formal parameter"
    // unless it is wrapped inside "DISABLE_ALL_WARNINGS" section
}
DISABLE_ALL_WARNINGS_END
```