# Disable warning at a specific place in Intel Compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, intel

I have a mathematical vector, whose dimensions I define with a template parameter `int N`. The problem is that I add to many parameters at the constructor for up to N=9, g++ was OK with this, but the Intel compiler is complaining about this with a warning

warning #175: subscript out of range

Yes, the subscript is out of range as it appears, but no, it's not gonna cause a problem, because it's written like this:

```
template <int N, typename T>
Vector<N,T>::Vector(T val0, T val1, T val2, T val3, T val4, T val5, T val6, T val7, T val8, T val9)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        _values[i] = T();
    }
    _values[0] = val0;
    if(N > 1)
        _values[1] = val1;
    if(N > 2)
        _values[2] = val2;
    if(N > 3)
        _values[3] = val3;
    if(N > 4)
        _values[4] = val4;
    if(N > 5)
        _values[5] = val5;
    if(N > 6)
        _values[6] = val6;
    if(N > 7)
        _values[7] = val7;
    if(N > 8)
        _values[8] = val8;
    if(N > 9)
        _values[9] = val9;
}
```

where N is the dimensionality, like I mentioned, and T is the data type. So the Intel compiler isn't smart enough to realize that this won't cause any problem since I don't access the element unless the the index is valid.

The question is: How can I tell the compiler with something like a macro/pre-compiler commands that it should not issue warning #175 for those lines? Notice that disabling warning #175 completely wouldn't be smart, though I could still do a real error somewhere else; I just want to disable it for this region of code.

Thanks for any efforts.

Comment: gcc uses '#pragma GCC diagnostic kind option'. msvc uses '#pragma warning (disable : number)'. They both have push/pop to work in specific region. I don't know if icc uses one of them or its own syntax.

Comment: why not to pass an array of size `N` instead of N parameters?

Comment: @Mario because the user will not be able to input the elements directly, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been said, you can disable the warnings with compiler specific `#pragma`s. The annoying thing of this solution is that it's not portable and some compilers emmit warnings when they find other compiler `#pragma`s. So you end up just trade warnings.

You can fix this issue with yet another `#pragma` or protecting the pragmas with

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO_DEFINED_BY_COMPILER_A
#pragma SOME_PRAGMA_FOR_COMPILER_A
#endif

#ifdef SOME_MACRO_DEFINED_BY_COMPILER_B
#pragma SOME_PRAGMA_FOR_COMPILER_B
#endif
```

I would rather make sure that no compiler sees code that can raise this warning. I would do something (not tested) like:

```
template <int i>
typename std::enable_if<(i < N)>::type
set(const T& val) {
    _values[i] = val;
}

template <int i>
typename std::enable_if<(i >= N)>::type
set(const T&) {
}

Vector(T val0, T val1, T val2, T val3, T val4, T val5, T val6, T val7, T val8, T val9) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        _values[i] = T();
    }
    _values[0] = val0;
    set<1>(val1);
    set<2>(val2);
    set<3>(val3);
    set<4>(val4);
    set<5>(val5);
    set<6>(val6);
    set<7>(val7);
    set<8>(val8);
    set<9>(val9);
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, do you know the preprocessor command to check for the intel compiler? I couldn't find it! Thanks.

Comment: @SamerAfach I'm not familiar with ICC but from [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/cpp/lin/bldaps_cls/cppug_ccl/bldaps_macros_lin.htm) I would say `__ICC`. See also [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/)

Comment: Thank you very much; I found it. It's "__INTEL_COMPILER". Cheers!

Comment: BTW... there's a horrible bug in the intel compiler... This can't be done by disabling and enabling warnings again... http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/283633

Answer (score 1):

As Jarod42 suggested you could use #pragmas to ignore warnings at particular locations and simple example is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525677/is-there-a-way-to-disable-all-warnings-with-a-pragma?rq=1).